# Converting Coordinates in Excel

Tags: qgis, coordinates, convert, excel

I am creating a spreadsheet of data to enter into QGIS.  My grid references are currently formatted like this: 339614, 133960 - they are the coordinates in the brackets on this site https://www.somersetheritage.org.uk/record/10571

But QGIS isn't registering them, I am struggling to find/work out what coordinate style QGIS accepts and how I can convert coordinates I have into the style required.

Please note that my spreadsheet, which a copy is saved as a .csv, is in excess of 1000 entries and is still growing.  So being able to convert them in bulk would be handy

Comment: Can you provide us a simplified (x, y coordinate cols and 1 or 2 other attributes col) CSV with headers and something like 2 lines? Can't guess from just a description. What is the coordinates reference/projection use for the x, y input?

Comment: What do you mean by "qgis isn't registering them" ? could you tell us how you are importing your spreadsheet in QGIS ? (a picture of the import dialog would help)

Comment: The coordinates are sources from this site https://www.somersetheritage.org.uk/record/10571

Comment: @RozJones please exceprt two to three coordinates from the source and add them to your question, since links are subject to change.

Comment: It is always the numbers in the brackets

Answer (score 1):

A demo

Use the following content (provided using data from your link) and save it in a CSV file named demo.csv (in fact, I use semicolon separator)

```
code;naming;old_nrhe;grid_ref;x;y
10571;Linear cropmark, NE of Greylake Bridge, Greylake;192187 (ST 33 SE 12);ST 396 339;339614;133960
```

Then, in QGIS, go to "Layer" menu > "Add Layer" > "Add Delimited Text Layer...", then fill the info like in my screenshot (choose 27700 for projection, used in UK) and finish by clicking "Add" then "Close"

[image: Text delimited config]

You will then see the point at the right place (e.g screenshot)

[image: End result overview]

PS: you could also use Excel/ODT input but more complex if you are a beginner, so I did not choose this "way".